# How to Call multiple functions in one onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I work on React Project and have a some functions which defines some conditions when render the components on page,
but I need to call to all functions again in components when onClick button and
render random numbers.

example:

```
export default function App(){

func1(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

func2(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

func3(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

const definedOne = func1();
const definedTwo = func2();
const defineTree = func3();

return(
 <div>{definedOne}<div>
 <div>{definedTwo}<div>
 <div>{definedTree}<div>
<button onClick={// what need to click?}>Run Functions Again</button>
)

}
```

Comment: The example doesn't use `onClick`?

Comment: `useState` for each number, then just update state.

Comment: Here are lot of codes, this is just an example. How Can I re-render this full components onClick? I think It's fixs my problem.

Comment: Your component will re-render when you change its state.  A convenient way to change state is with a [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your values, you have to cause a render by updating a state, maybe be doing this way

```
export default function App(){

func1(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

func2(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

func3(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

const obj = () => ({
    definedOne: func1(),
    definedTwo: func2(),
    definedThree: func3()
})

const [state, setState] = useState(obj())

return(
 <div>{state.definedOne}<div>
 <div>{state.definedTwo}<div>
 <div>{state.definedTree}<div>
<button onClick={() => {
    setState({...obj()})
}}>Run Functions Again</button>
)

}
```

Comment: Yes I've made so, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

You code for React is incomplete. TO get a button to work, you need code such as this:

```
<Button
   variant="outline-secondary"
   id="button-addon2"
   disabled={email === ''}
   onClick={() => sendReport()}>
   Send report
 </Button>
```

Now this will calls a function named sendReport(). For example:

const sendReport = async () => {
service.mailItem(email).catch((e) => {setError(e.message)});
}

Your code has no **onClick()** method.

Answer (score 1):

Your three numbers need to be [moved to state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), which enables you to update them on click.

Use a `handleClick` function to update the three state variables.

```
export default function App(){

func1(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

func2(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

func3(){
 // some func
//brings random number
}

handleClick(){
  setDefinedOne(func1());
  setDefinedTwo(func2());
  setDefinedThree(func3());
}

const [definedOne, setDefinedOne] = useState(func1());
const [definedTwo, setDefinedTwo] = useState(func2());
const [definedThree, setDefinedThree] = useState(func3());

return(
 <div>{definedOne}<div>
 <div>{definedTwo}<div>
 <div>{definedTree}<div>
<button onClick={handleClick}>Run Functions Again</button>
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` function can be used like this :

> onClick = {handleClickFn}

or

> onClick = {(e) => handleClickFn(e)}

Both works fine.

```
export default function App(){

   const handleClickFn = (e) => {
      console.log("You clicked button");

      func1();
      func2();
      func3();
   }

   func1(){
     // some func
     //brings random number
   }

   func2(){
      // some func
      //brings random number
   }

   func3(){
      // some func
      //brings random number
    }

   const definedOne = func1();
   const definedTwo = func2();
   const defineTree = func3();

   return(
      <div>{definedOne}<div>
      <div>{definedTwo}<div>
      <div>{definedTree}<div>
      <button onClick={handleClickFn}>Run Functions Again</button>
   )

}
```